# Как обернуть ссылкой контейнер с сохранением правил css для внутренних элементов?

Tags: css, css3

Трудно мне с css, очень трудно. А особые трудности возникают при обертывании контейнера, например `<div>` с внутренними элементами тегом `<a>`. Например, в блоке новостей находится контейнер с картинкой и описанием новости. Контейнер оборачивается ссылкой, чтобы при клике переходить на соответствующую запись. 
Так вот при таком оборачивании ссылкой, все стили элементов теряются - устанавливаются стандартный стиль тега `<a>`. И так везде.

Неужели я должен для каждого конкретного случая прописывать для элементов, обернутых тегом `<a>`,  определенные правила???

Например:

```
    <a href=#>
     <div>
     <img src='/news231.png' />
     <p>..........</p>
     <h2>.........</h2>
     ................
    </div>
   </a>
```

Comment: Я не могу отформатировать!

Comment: @soledar10 изменил вопрос. Добавил пример. И таких модулей может быть сколько угодно на странице в различных комбинациях.

Comment: как вариант назначить ссылке class="link-news" (это произвольное назвнание класса)  и тогда придется для блока обернутого ссылкой - прописать стили.

Comment: @soledar10, вот об этом речь и шла. Теперь буду заранее прогнозировать контейнеры, которые будут обернуты и не нервничать))). Комментарий сделайте ответом, я зачту)))

Comment: Deus сделал ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант назначить ссылке `class="link-news"` (это произвольное название класса) и тогда придется для блока обернутого ссылкой - прописать стили.

Comment: Я знаю, что такое ссылка и что такое псевдокласс :hover. Обобщу вопрос - если я оберну весь код страницы ссылкой, то мне придется заново переписать все стили для каждого элемента?

Comment: а такой вариант приемлем? http://jsfiddle.net/48q19htt/

Comment: Видимо, вы не поняли меня. Я хочу, чтобы блок оставался таким, будто вообще не существует тега "a". Обертка нужна только для клика - кликнул  -и читаешь новость! Так вот этот тег ломает все правила элементов. Вот и всё. Я оформляю блок новости - вот картинка, вот подпись, вот небольшой анонс - красота! Оборачиваю ссылкой - и опять приходится прописывать новые стили...

Comment: принял ваш ответ только из-за одного вашего слова "придется". Это решило все мои проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про CSS-селекторы.
Каждому элементу HTML можно задать такие атрибуты как `class` и `id`, затем, при написании стилей задавать определенные стили для соответствующих `id`, `class`.
Например:

```
<a class="one" id="first" >...</a>
<a class="two" id="second" >...</a>

<style>
  a.one{/* стили для первой ссылки */}
  a#first{/* стили для первой ссылки */}
  a.two{/* стили для второй ссылки */}
  a#second{/* стили для второй ссылки */}
</style>
```

Comment: Я знаю, что такое "а", сто такое селекторы и все остальное, связанное с css.Видимо, вы не поняли меня. Я хочу, чтобы блок оставался таким, будто вообще не существует тега "a". Обертка нужна только для клика - кликнул -и читаешь новость! Так вот этот тег ломает все правила элементов. Вот и всё. Я оформляю блок новости - вот картинка, вот подпись, вот небольшой анонс - красота! Оборачиваю ссылкой - и опять приходится прописывать новые стили...

Comment: @Deus есть ещё такой вариант: тег <a> - вставить внутри div'a, затем div сделать relative, тег а - 100% по высоте и ширине, и задать ему z-index. Таким образом тег <a> будет размером с div, и немного приподнят над ним по оси z. Ссылка будет срабатывать. Стили останутся целы.

Comment: Да все ок.  Я убедился, что для каждого блока, обернутого ссылкой, необходимо прописывать отдельные стили. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: ну вы даете ))). скоро появится yxz-index, так что мы будем иметь возможность приподнимать обертки в трех-мерном пространстве!